# Finding Potential Primary Key In Tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have tables(more than 100) that are missing primary keys. Actually, these are legacy tables. Now as per some replication requirements, we need to add primary key on each of these tables. Is there any way to find out possible primary keys on a table (ready to purchase a commercial product)?

Comment: In general - noway. In particular... IDENTITY is PK - 100%, UUID is PK - 90%, column with at least duplicated value or with at least one NULL is not PK - 100%.

Comment: To add onto what Akina said, columns that are part of a unique constraint *can* also be a Primary Key.

Comment: @J.D. Yea I know but question is how can I figure it out that these are unique and possible PKs

Comment: [This](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/09/08/sql-server-find-unique-key-columns-sp_special_columns-customers/) post by Pinal Dave might help.

Comment: Thanks @SqlWorldWide. Does `sp_special_columns` can tell me possible primary key

Comment: This can help you find unique keys on SQL Server tables but not necessarily Primary Key.

Comment: @SqlWorldWide but what if they are not marked as unique constraint?

Comment: @user960567 If they are not marked as a unique constraint, and there are no columns marked as Primary Key, then it's not possible for SQL Server to tell you what your Primary Key is. That is something you, as the developer, needs to decide based on your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the criteria for what constitutes a "possible primary key". When you have done that, you/we can search for (for instance sp_special_columns) or produce a script that uses that criteria. Such criteria could be:

1. A unique index on the column(s) (possibly created using a unique constraint).
2. The table has a column having the IDENTITY property.
3. A column of the uniqueidentifier data type (but that could very well also be a foreign key).
4. A column or set of columns which in the data has no duplicates.

For 3 and 4, you are gambling, since having no duplicates today is not guarantee that there should be duplicates tomorrow.

In general, there is a risk messing about in a database unless you own the database. Say that you slap on an identity column on each table, make it the PK, just so you can use replication. Now, there might be some code that does SELECT * and breaks down because it now gets this additional column that you added.

Comment: Actually, for now we are analyzing possible duplicates. We are looking 4 point actually.

Comment: Do you know any commercial support of this?